# JQueryのDatatableプラグインで、テーブルにaタグを追加したいです。

Tags: jquery

jQuery用のプラグイン、[Datatable](http://holt59.github.io/datatable/) を使っています。

```
var setData = [];
// ループ
    var tbledata = {};
    tbledata.testA = "テスト";
    var $inputdata = $('<input>', {
        name: 'id',
        value: "inputタグテスト"
    });
    tbledata.id = $inputdata[0].outerHTML;
    setData.push(tbledata);
// ループ終了

// テーブルデータ追加
$('#tabletest').datatable('insert', setData);
$('#tabletest').datatable('refresh');

//tabletest→tableタグのID
```

このような形で、HTMLのテーブルに、

テスト、　inputタグテスト　と表示ができました。
ここで、inputタグテストにリンクを張らせたいと思い、以下のような感じで考えてみたもののうまくいきません…。何か良い方法はないでしょうか。

```
    var $adata = $('<a>', {
        name: 'atest',
        value: "リンクテスト",
    });
    tbledata.atest = $adata [0].outerHTML;
```

Comment: `datatable` というメソッドは `jQuery` には無さそうですが、プラグインの物ですか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。すみません。情報不足でした。おっしゃる通りプラグインになります。http://holt59.github.io/datatable/